# Jquery | Get div elements in defined area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

is there a simple way to get the `div` elements fitting completely in a defined area?

Example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oIw6i.png]

```
<div id="redbox"> RESIZE DIV </div>

<div id="grid">
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
  <div id="box4"></div>
</div>
```

I got 4 Boxes (grey) and I am able to resize a `div` (red on top of all boxes). After resize I want to know which of the div elements are fitting completely in this area.

Does anyone knows how to do this? Is there a method or function in `JQUERY`?

Comment: Upvoting for having the patience to attach a meaningful graphic. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to me like the `withinBox` plugin might help you solve this ([`jquery.fn.withinBox`](http://donejs.com/docs.html#!jQuery.fn.withinBox)). You could use the code like this:

```
var area = $('#redbox'),
    offset = area.offset(),
    selected = $('#grid div').withinBox(offset.left,
                                        offset.top,
                                        area.width(),
                                        area.height()
                                        );
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is what I need. I have to figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

What I'd do with JQuery is loop through all the elements to check, getting their `.offset()` value, plus **width** and **height**.

Then for each element I'll get these four valuyes:

```
X1 (offset().top)
Y1 (offset().left)
X2 (= X1 + width)
Y2 (= Y1 + height)
```

I will use these values to check the following four points (still for each element to check)

```
x1,y1  x1,y2  x2,y2  x2,y1  (the four corners)
```

Provided we have done the same tring with the "covering" DIV (retrieving it's four corners  xd1, yd1, xd2, yd2), I will reason like this:

> If **one or more** of these points falls into my "covering" DIV, then consider the DIV "covered".

**Edit:** I didn't know there was a plugin for that, I guess it's internal mechanics are like mine, but I bet it's a more simple solution than mine :)

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what the `withinBox` plugin does. +1 for explaining it!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i cannot use the existing plugin `withinBox`, this is how I'm going to calculate it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is already complete solution for this. According that this may various.

But you can use [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) function for that.

Knowing absolute position of re-sizable `div` you can create map of coordinates and then see what elements under that `div`.